# Add stock data on product programatically in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, create-product

I want to add stock data on a product but it doesn't work. In my function, I have a product created by :

```
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
```

Then, I set some data like price, status, name, ... And eventually, I add a code for the stock :

```
$product->setStockData(array(
            'use_config_manage_stock' => (bool)0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
            'manage_stock' => (bool)1, //manage stock
            'min_sale_qty' => 0, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
            'max_sale_qty' => 0, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
            'is_in_stock' => (bool)1, //Stock Availability
            'qty' => 0 //qty
            )
        );
```

I don't want that the product inherit the config settings and I absolutly want a quantity different of null (0 or greater).

But, when the function is launched, the product is created, every data is ok exept the stock data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to give intval for your qty to set int value of qty.

```
       $product->setStockData(array(
            'use_config_manage_stock' => (bool)0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
            'manage_stock' => (bool)1, //manage stock
            'min_sale_qty' => 0, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
            'max_sale_qty' => 0, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
            'is_in_stock' => (bool)1, //Stock Availability
            'qty' => (intval)0 //qty
            )
        )
      try {
            $product->save(); 
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getException();
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, but still doesn't work because of the "use_config_manage_stock" set as true despite the ```'use_config_manage_stock' => (bool)0```